# Deleting a record does a PUT of the parent object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models, Loan and Product, and Loan hasMany Products. In my rest adapter mapping I have the following:

```
App.CustomAdapter.map("App.Loan",
    products:
        embedded: 'always'
        key: "products_attributes"
    )
```

And when I try to do this:

```
    product.deleteRecord()
    product.get("store").commit()
```

Instead of sending a request with verb DELETE with the product to the server I get a PUT request for Loan sent to the server, so my Product record is not deleted.

Is this a side effect of what I did in the mappings? and what would be a work around?

Also I noticed that when I do toJSON on my product model no id is serialized.

Comment: as for this *Also I noticed that when I do toJSON on my product model no id is serialized.* add `{includeId: true}` , e.g. `product.toJSON({includeId: true});` to the `toJSON` call.

Comment: the id is sent as part of the URL, so wont be serialized into the payload. i have the same problem with the HTTP verbs